# Extract all instances of variables matching a pattern?

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

There is a very convenient function `Dt` that allows to take a total differential of any expression, e.g.:

```
expr = (a + b c)/d;
Dt[expr]
```

> `(Dt[a] + c Dt[b] + b Dt[c])/d - ((a + b c) Dt[d])/d^2`

Consider a case where `expr` is generic (it is not known a priori which and how many variables appear). I would like to have a function that extracts a list of all `Dt[x_]` from an expression. For the above example it should do:

```
extract[Dt[expr]]
```

> `{Dt[a],Dt[b],Dt[c],Dt[d]}`

My own version of this function is:

```
extract[x_] := Select[Variables[x], (Head[#] === Dt) &]
```

but I feel like extracting all variables and then selecting a subset is too hacky. Is there a nice way to implement this?

**EDIT**

Bob Hanlon and Mr. Wizard suggested to use `Cases` and `Union`. Unfortunately, these functions appear to be slower than the above in some cases:

```
Select[Variables[ Dt[(a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q]], (Head[#] === Dt) &] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.0000811731, {Dt[a], Dt[b], Dt[c], Dt[d], Dt[q]}}`

compared to

```
Cases[Dt[(a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q], _Dt, {-2}] // Union // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.000136221, {Dt[a], Dt[b], Dt[c], Dt[d], Dt[q]}}`

Comment: `Cases[Dt[expr], _Dt, Infinity] // Union`

Comment: @BobHanlon Or slightly shorter: `Cases[Dt[expr], _Dt, {-2}] // Union` -- the single level search should be somewhat faster with large expressions as well.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard BobHanlon Thank you for the suggestions! Unfortunately that does not yield a speed up. See the edit of my question.

Comment: `Union@Cases[expr, HoldPattern[Dt[_]], 
  Infinity]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the various methods proposed in comments, plus a hybrid, I find my proposal fastest:

```
foo = Dt[(a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q + ((a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q)/z + 
    q r ((a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q + ((a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q)/z)];

Select[Variables @ foo, (Head[#] === Dt) &]      // RepeatedTiming

Cases[foo, _Dt, Infinity] // Union               // RepeatedTiming

foo // Variables // Cases[_Dt]                   // RepeatedTiming

Union@Cases[foo, HoldPattern[Dt[_]], Infinity]   // RepeatedTiming

Cases[foo, _Dt, {-2}] // Union                   // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0000269, {Dt[a], Dt[b], Dt[c], Dt[d], Dt[q], Dt[r], Dt[z]}}
>
> {0.00002049, {Dt[a], Dt[b], Dt[c], Dt[d], Dt[q], Dt[r], Dt[z]}}
>
> {0.000019798, {Dt[a], Dt[b], Dt[c], Dt[d], Dt[q], Dt[r], Dt[z]}}
>
> {0.00001882, {Dt[a], Dt[b], Dt[c], Dt[d], Dt[q], Dt[r], Dt[z]}}
>
> {0.0000145, {Dt[a], Dt[b], Dt[c], Dt[d], Dt[q], Dt[r], Dt[z]}}
> ```

Comment: Guess, I was not using the correct timing function. Sorry about that!

Comment: Wouldn't the results be more accurate if you precede each line with `ClearSystemCache[];`?

Comment: @BobHanlon I don't see why that would be needed in this case, and using it doesn't appear to change the result.  Were we using something like `Simplify` I think it would be another story.

Comment: On my system (Mac) I got a slightly different ordering using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = 
Dt[(a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q + ((a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q)/z + 
 q r ((a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q + ((a + b c)/d + (a + b c)/d q)/
     z)];

Union@Level[foo, {-2}] // Cases[#, _Dt] &
(* {Dt[a], Dt[b], Dt[c], Dt[d], Dt[q], Dt[r], Dt[z]} *)
```

or

```
Select[Union@Level[expr, {-2}], (Head@# === Dt)&]
```